# etherscan verification for newly deployed contracts

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, etherscan

from my UI, I call a contract function through `ethers.js` that deploys a new contract. It's like user comes to the UI, clicks a button that calls a contract function and then, that contract function deploys a new contract.

Since lots of users will be doing this and they will have new contracts each time, I am looking for a way how to offer some kind of service so that these contracts automatically get verified. Without this, My software creates contracts for them, but they aren't verified.

Is something feasible through etherscan API ?

**I don't want this way:** When the new contract gets created, I also have an abi at that point, so what I can do is send an etherscan verification, but the problem here is that when contract gets created, you should wait for like 1 minute before you submit it for verification on etherscan, otherwise, most of the times, it's anyways gonna fail. So I can't let users wait for another 1 min.. I don't have a back-end service either and not planning on it.

What do you think how can this be achieved easily ?

Answer (score 0):

Doesnt etherscan automatically verify the contract if another contract with matching bytecode is already deployed and verified?